# Как решить проблему в установке Yii2 advanced?

Tags: yii2, composer

Почему при установке Yii2 advanced через архив https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced нет папки vendor,

а при скачивании через composer (код и скрины ниже) нет index.php и других в web/fronted и backend/web? php -init выполнялась и токен запрашивался,хосты настроены, но сейчас в браузере появились ошибки при запросе fronted и backend

```
    PHP User Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'The file or directory to be published does not exist: D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2/vendor\bower/jquery/dist' 

in D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\AssetManager.php:454

Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\AssetBundle.php(185): yii\web\AssetManager->publish('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#1 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\AssetManager.php(268): yii\web\AssetBundle->publish(Object(yii\web\AssetManager))
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\AssetManager.php(239): yii\web\AssetManager->loadBundle('yii\\web\\JqueryA...', Array, true)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\View.php(286): yii\web\AssetManager->getBundle('yii\\web\\JqueryA...')
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\View.php(291): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('yii\\web\\JqueryA...', NULL)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\View.php(291): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('yii\\web\\YiiAsse...', NULL)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\AssetBundle.php(125): yii\web\View->registerAssetBundle('yii\\validators\\...')
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\validators\RequiredValidator.php(91): yii\web\AssetBundle::register(Object(yii\web\View))
#8 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(763): yii\validators\RequiredValidator->clientValidateAttribute(Object(common\models\LoginForm), 'username', Object(yii\web\View))
#9 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(230): yii\widgets\ActiveField->getClientOptions()
#10 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(220): yii\widgets\ActiveField->begin()
#11 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-bootstrap\ActiveField.php(187): yii\widgets\ActiveField->render('<label class="c...')
#12 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php(176): yii\bootstrap\ActiveField->render()
#13 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\backend\views\site\login.php(22): yii\widgets\ActiveField->__toString()
#14 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(330): require('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#15 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(250): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array)
#16 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(152): yii\base\View->renderFile('D:\\xampp\\htdocs...', Array, Object(backend\controllers\SiteController))
#17 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(381): yii\base\View->render('login', Array, Object(backend\controllers\SiteController))
#18 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\backend\controllers\SiteController.php(82): yii\base\Controller->render('login', Array)
#19 [internal function]: backend\controllers\SiteController->actionLogin()
#20 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#21 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#22 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): yii\base\Controller->runAction('login', Array)
#23 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(102): yii\base\Module->runAction('site/login', Array)
#24 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#25 D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2\backend\web\index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#26 {main}
```

[image: 1][image: 2][image: 3]
[image: 4]

Answer (score 0):

В yii2 есть несколько состояний фрейморка
к пример dev ( режим разработки )
и prod ( подакшн, режим пользования)

Когда вы скачали фрейморк, вам нужно запустить в консоле php init
и выбрать какой режим вы хотите инифиализировать, тогда появятся не достающие файлы

а папка vendor динамична, потому что там много зависимостей, если вы будите скачивать архив для ручной установки  - там она будет, в ссылке которую вы дали, нужно через composer запустить

Comment: файл php-init запускался как файл и где выбраны опции 0 и development и 2 раз в консоли -файлы index.php появились.  а папка vendor  2-м способом установилась через composer и токен, как её запустить через архив тогда? сейчас в браузере вылезли ошибки и код какой-то  -на скринах ниже можно посмотреть .

Comment: вы не тот архив скачали. Если вы устанавливаете через этот архив сделайте composer update , подтянутся зависимости и вендор, потом инициализируйте

Comment: $ composer update
Composer could not find a composer.json file in D:\xampp\htdocs\yii2-app-advance      d
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the       https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section

Comment: $ Composer self-update
пишет что (не умещается код) 
You are already using composer version 1.4.2 (stable channel).